# Is this operation correct for chain operations?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I am doing an Computer Architecture project for my studies.
Among others my system should do chain operations using direct indexed addressing.
So is this operation technically correct?

REP MOVS AX, [SI]

Comment: You're inventing your own architecture, apparently, so you *can* use different syntax or mnemonics than x86 if you want.  In x86, `movs` copies from memory to memory.  With those operands, only `lods` really fits for x86 (and `rep lods` is weird).  But sure, that syntax could make sense for your equivalent of x86's `rep stos`.  See http://felixcloutier.com/x86/REP:REPE:REPZ:REPNE:REPNZ.html

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't use my own syntax because lecturer doesn't accept it. So do you think that this operation should be correct? I have to have this chain operation with direct indexed addressing.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've already been to him 3 times and always there was something that he complains. "Oh it's technically correct but I don't like it. It's not like I want it to be" and that's all

Comment: Wait, are you actually trying to program x86, *not* make up your own new architecture?  `rep movsw` doesn't touch AX, it's a memcpy from [SI] to [DI].  What do you actually want your instruction to do?  (And BTW, "chain" is not a word normally used in x86 manuals.)